# undefined method `shuffle' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The similar user random order `shuffle` is no longer working from the controller. Can someone assist me with the code?

User model:

```
  def similar
      arr = User.where(:gender => self.gender).where.not(:id => self.id)
      arr.select{ |c|
          if !c.location.nil? 
              return c.location.state == self.location.try(:state)
          else
              return false
          end
      }
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try removing the instances of the word `return` from `similar`.  Those return statements cause `similar` to return true or false instead of returning an array.

You can actually use `next` to return values from a block but it's not needed here.

Also, use a version control system so you can revert back to working code when needed.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the issue there.